# Adding to a container on main from a class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, containers

Ive been working at this for an hour and I cant get it. I'm trying to add an object to a container on the main timeline from a class. Whenever I try and do this, it allows me to run the game but will give me an output error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property container not found on flash.display.Stage and there is no default value.
```

Here is the code for my main:

```
var dotContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
stage.addChild(dotContainer);
```

And here is the code for my Class:

```
package  {
    public class dotMaker extends MovieClip 
    {
         var dot:MovieClip = new Dot;
         Object(root).dotContainer.addChild(dot);
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your `dotContainer` code on timeline?

Comment: Yes it is @RajneeshGaikwad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a class, it doesn't know what you've added to the stage. So you should use the `name` property and get it like that:

```
var dotContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
dotContainer.name = 'dotContainer';
stage.addChild(dotContainer);


package  {
    public class dotMaker extends MovieClip 
    {
        var dot:MovieClip = new Dot;
        (Object(root).getChildByName('dotContainer') as DisplayObjectContainer).addChild(dot);
    }
}
```

You should know that such things are not pretty good to do. It's better to use it like this:

```
public class dotMaker extends MovieClip {
    var _container:DisplayObjectContainer;

    public function dotMaker(container:DisplayObjectContainer) {
        _container = container;
        _container.addChild(new Dot());
    }
}
```

So pass the container to this class so it can work with it.
Another strange thing is that you don't use constructor?

Comment: Thankyou! and I forgot to put the constructor in for this question